# Fade a div when I begin to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed header when I begin to scroll the header changes its height and removes the logo. What I would like to do is have the logo fadeout instead of just disappearing. How can I achieve this effect?

For testing purposes I am unable to display my logo in jsfiddle because it is a custom font so I will be using #mainlogo as my example. Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/Bx4rq/9/

**JS**

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 30){  
  $('#headerWrapper, .icon-lkbl, #mainLogo, .nav-collapse').addClass("sticky");
      }
        else{
  $('#headerWrapper, .icon-lkbl, #mainLogo, .nav-collapse').removeClass("sticky");
 }
 });
```

**CSS**

```
 #headerWrapper.sticky { height: 48px; }
 .icon-lkbl.sticky,  #mainLogo.sticky { display:none;}
 .nav-collapse.sticky{ margin-top:-10px;}
```

HTML

```
  <div id="headerWrapper">
        <header>
              <a href="#" rel="home">
                    <div class="iconMain icon-lkbl"></div>
                    <h1 id="mainLogo">Logo <strong>Test</strong></h1>
              </a>
  <nav id="mainNav" class="nav-collapse">
        <ul>
              <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="recipes.html">Recipes</a></li>
              <li><a href="garden.html">Garden</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" rel="popuprel" class="iconMain icon-search search popup">       <span>Search</span></a></li>
        </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="popupbox" id="popuprel">
        <div id="searchPanel">
              <h2><span>Find your</span> next meal</h2>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div id="fade"></div>
  </header>
  </div> <!-- END HEADER WRAPPER -->
```

Comment: Your fiddle does not seem to demonstrate the described current behavior.

Comment: Where do i scroll in that fiddle..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of showing and hiding using display: none;

you can use jquerys, fadein and fadeout.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 30) {
        $('#headerWrapper, .icon-lkbl, #mainLogo, .nav-collapse').addClass("sticky");
        $('.icon-lkbl, #mainLogo').fadeOut();
    }
    else {
        $('#headerWrapper, .icon-lkbl, #mainLogo, .nav-collapse').removeClass("sticky");
        $('.icon-lkbl, #mainLogo').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

[fadein documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

Comment: I'm trying I have to wait a few minutes @svendjokumsen. The moment it allows me I will